# Not able to set key value pairs in properties files in protractor when using npm Properties-Reader

Tags: javascript, npm, protractor, properties-file

i am using the npm module Properties-Reader for reading and writing properties file in Protractor Automation framework. The Utility method created is :

```
var PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');
var path = require('path');

//var properties = PropertiesReader('../Resources/test.properties');

var PropertyFileReader = function(){


    this.readPropertyFiles = function(filePath){

        var fileToRead = filePath;
        absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToRead);

        var properties = PropertiesReader(absolutePath);
        return properties;


    }
```

I am successfully get the items stored in the properties files by using the command as

```
 var property = propertyReader.readPropertyFiles('D:/ProtractorDemo/Project05/BE/QA/Utils/sett.properties')
var name = property.get('name');
      console.log(name);
```

But on using the set(), method i am not able to set anything in my properties files. Also. there is no error shown on the console. My properties files still remains empty

```
property.set('age', '28');
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are receiving?

Comment: Hi, I am not getting any error, but also my properties file remain empty. Nothing is written or set in it.

Comment: My mistake I misread the last part of your question. Could you add the structure of the file you are reading or include a snippet of what it looks like?

Comment: The file is stored as : test.properties. It has the 2 key value pairs:name = ashish
age  = 30. using x.get(), i am able to retrieve the values, but not able to set a new value like x.set('test', 'mytest') using the code mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact purpose of this package but I can see that despite the source properties file not being updated `set` is actually adding the value to the loaded properties file in memory. Use `console.log(property.get('age'));` after your set and you'll see it updated. I'm unsure if `set` is even supposed to update the original file based on the [source coude](https://github.com/steveukx/properties/blob/237409bf04ebd3274a8ee4f1106cb0e9f38248df/src/PropertiesReader.js#L151)